# Regex which accept any value but of maximum 200 of length in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to make a regex that accepts any input combination, but the condition is text must be of less than 200 characters.

for example

```
'123ababb' => valid
'abbd$5%' => valid
```

I used the following regex but it doesn't match for any special character.

`[a-zA-Z0-9  .,']{0,200}`

Comment: easy - `.{0,200}`

Comment: Well why are you providing a character group in the first place then, instead of just using `.`?

Comment: Why you use regex for that? Why not just check `.length`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using regex, in this case, is not a good option
because usually, we use to regex to create a special pattern or find something in a string.

in your case, I suggest using `.length`

for example:

```
let your_string = 'anyStringYouWant';
consloe.log('string length:' , your_string.length);
if (your_string.length > 200) {
    console.log('string length is bigger than 200')
}
```